# Assistance with JavaScript sum function

Tags: javascript, html

New to posting but have been to this site +/- x1000.

I'm really looking to get some information on how to extend this script to calculate more form fields.

Currently this html\jscript page will perform a SUM calculation on 2 form fields using the OnChange event. Everything works great but I'm unable to add additional fields into the scope of calculation.

Below is the working code, please let me know if you want to see my current code attempt.
Really appreciate any help you can offer. Thank You.

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Calulate</title> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function calc(A,B,SUM) { 
  var one = Number(A); 
  if (isNaN(one)) { alert('Invalid entry: '+A); one=0; } 
  var two = Number(document.getElementById(B).value); 
  if (isNaN(two)) { alert('Invalid entry: '+B); two=0; } 
  document.getElementById(SUM).value = one + two;
} 
</script> 

<body> 
<form name="form" > 
Enter a number: 
<input name="sum1" id="op1" value="" onChange="calc(this.value,'op2','result')" /> 
and another number: 
<input name="sum2" id="op2" value="" onChange="calc(this.value,'op1','result')" /> 
<br>
Their sum is: 
<input name="sum" value="" id="result" readonly style="border:0px;"> 
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are of course several ways to write a function that calculates the sum of several inputs. I'm going to do this by extending on what you already have, so that you'll gain some better understanding on what the code you did have was actually doing. In the end, there may be better solutions that would involve complete rewrites.

You'd have to add the markup for data input:

```
and a third number: 
<input name="sum3" id="op3" value="" />
```

Your function declaration would have to be modified to accept one more parameter:

```
function calc(A,B,C,SUM) {
```

Your function body would have to treat this parameter like `A` and `B` is treated:

```
var three = Number(document.getElementById(C).value); 
if (isNaN(three)) { alert('Invalid entry: '+C); three=0; }
```

Your sum would have to take this new number into account:

```
document.getElementById(SUM).value = one + two + three;
```

All three input fields would have to have their `onChange` attributes updated, to pass the new `C` parameter that we've defined:

```
<input name="sum1" id="op1" value="" onChange="calc(this.value,'op2','op3','result')" /> 
<input name="sum2" id="op2" value="" onChange="calc(this.value,'op1','op3','result')" /> 
<input name="sum3" id="op3" value="" onChange="calc(this.value,'op1','op2','result')" />
```

---

Now, to give you an idea of what you might do differently altogether, instead of accessing the elements by ID, you could access them by class name. For instance, you could add the class name `calc` to all three input fields. You could either let this class name be known by the function, or pass it as an argument. In that case, the function would not need to receive `A`, `B` and `C`, but it would only need the class name and the ID of the output field.

```
function(className, SUM) {
    ...
}
```

Inside your function, you would then be able to find all elements of that class name:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
```

and iterate over them, adding the values as you go:

```
var sum = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    var input = inputs[i];
    var num = Number(input.value);

    if(isNaN(num)) { 
        alert('Invalid value: ' + input.value);
        num = 0;
    }

    sum += num;
}

document.getElementById(SUM).value = sum;
```

You would then add class names and update your `onChange` attributes like so:

```
<input name="sum1" class="calc" onChange="calc('calc','result')" /> 
<input name="sum2" class="calc" onChange="calc('calc','result')" /> 
<input name="sum3" class="calc" onChange="calc('calc','result')" />
```

You would then be able to add any number of input fields, and they would automatically be calculated without modifying the function.

Comment: Great! That is exactly what I was after. I really do appreciate the code breakdown and will be applying the extensions ASAP. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to have a dynamic list of input fields, which are marked by a specific class (`numbers` in the below code). Your function could the first get a list of all such fields and run through all of them to sum them up.

```
function calc( classId, sumId ) {
  var els = document.querySelectorAll( '.' + classId ),
      sum = 0;

  for( var i=0, max=els.length; i<max; ++i ) {
     if( isNaN( els[i].value ) ) { 
       alert('Invalid entry: '+ els[i].value );
     } else {
       sum += els[i].value;
     }
  }

  document.getElementById( sumId ).value = sum;
}
```

Your input fields would then look like this:

```
<input name="sum2" id="op2" value="" class="numbers" onChange="calc( 'numbers', 'result' );" />
```

Two things to note:

1. Older browsers do not support `document.querySelectorAll`. You may need a polyfill here.
2. It would be better to assign the events by JS, too.

The second could be realised as follows:

```
(function(){
  var els = document.querySelectorAll( '.' + inClass ),
      classId = 'numbers',
      sumId = 'result';

  for( var i=0, max=els.length; i<max; ++i ) {
     els[i].addEventListener( 'change', function(){ calc( classId, sumId ); } );
  }
})();
```

Comment: Thanks that is a great idea as well. To add more detail, this code goes into a static form with a certain number of fields that must be filled. Dynamic fields would be nice if I did not require all fields that are viewable to be completed. I will keep it in mind for another idea I have brewing.